# Android - Embed Custom Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I want to embed a custom map inside android app. It is possible? And if yes - how?

The goal is to show specific places around you.
I can create a map and put markers on it (client-side/java) with coordinates I get from my server.
But, I would like, if possible, Google's MapFragment to handle this task and update the markers on the map. We'll add the relative markers server-side via google maps engine API.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to create the map using the [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) and then load that map into a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Otherwise, you can use a [MapView](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html) for Android. If you store all the marker data on your servers, you can load [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) onto the map at whatever update cycles you indicate. When and how you pull the data will depend on how your server functions.